# how to turn off whitespace normalization for <pre> tagged html content scraped using Beni Bela's simpleinternet.pas

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, lazarus

```
secMyObj := process('http://www.example.com/'+v.toNode.getAttribute('href'),'/html');

myAppendFn(secMyObj.toNode.innerHTML(true)); //true for whitespace enabling to prevent a long one line html string
```

First all html content is scraped from the dynamically constructed absolute url. The innerHTML is then passed to a custom function which appends it as CData node content in a resultant XML file.

My problem is that the scraped pre /pre section isn't the replica of the same section in source html file, causing formatting problems.

If possible can someone suggest a workaround in delphi/lazarus(preferred) to get a faithful copy of the whole html page from its url quickly for batch processing tasks?

**Edit:**
To be precise, as the source paragraph(in pre section) consisted of a lot of &nbsp 's, the html rendered sentences appear to be broken.

At code level, The substance(html-tags/text/&nbsp 's) is all the same but spaces are different as shown below  (left is source, right is scraped one):
[image: using beyond compare: left is source, right is scraped one]

Comment: Do you know what a self contained minimal reproducible example is?

Comment: the scraped content can't be posted directly for privacy reason.

Comment: so make up your own example. that screenshot is absurd.

Comment: since pre tags bother about whitespaces, can you see from the picture that the rendered output will be different? how to achieve that code+whitespace replication is my question. @Warren is an example needed now?

Comment: Using `process` function you get not the page source but it DOM representation (or something). If you need just a page source why you are not using `retrieve` function instead?

Comment: is the page source(code) different from DOM representation? The technique worked for everything except the <pre></pre> part.

Comment: Feel free to ask the question your way. We'll just close it though.

Comment: FWIW, it is hard to see anything useful from the picture. Use your own test html and output. The test html can contain some text that has no privacy issues.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis As for me the question is absolutely clear: "Why `innerHTML` value is not same to source HTML and how to fix this?" :)

Answer (score 1):

I initially planned to store the page html(including pre section) as an XML CData node and render it directly afterwards with an HTML output control. Since the rendered output differed(effectively) in whitespaces only, I have changed my mind to do

```
myAppendFn(secMyObj.toString);
```

This isn't really the answer, but toString() does the job of preserving text and its alignment(spacing or whatever) at the cost of lost html coloring or other such formatting that existed within the pre section, and of course with a lot less stuff to save in the target CData node.

Delphi custom functions can then be used to make up for formatting in a synEdit or richEdit that is used for text rendering instead of html rendering.